# How do I match "obj.foo" in a function declaration string

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a function expression represented as a string

```
"var someFunction = function (foo) { foo.bar = 'hello'; };"
```

How can I identify all valid (in terms of js syntax) references to foo.bar safely in that string?

i.e. avoiding instances like `"catfoo.barbar"` I would like to replace these references with something else.

(And someone is certainly going to ask... yes I am using eval, and yes it makes sense in my use case)

---

The most important thing I am looking for really is how to match valid object name. How would I match the set of all valid characters in an object name? What are they even? Characters like áéíóú are apparently valid characters, so it's a bit more complicated than `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`

To illustrate what I actually want to do. I have a function in which I am injecting objects with properties

```
function shader(src, dst, out) {
    out.a = (src.a + dst.a)/2;
}
```

This gets invoked for each pixel on a 2D canvas. What I would like to do is inline this function, and remove all of the dot operators in a sensible manner.

```
...
var src = {}, dst = {}, out = {};
...

for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
    shader(src, dst, out);
}
```

After inlining the shader becomes

```
...
var src = {}, dst = {}, out = {};
...

for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
   out.a = (src.a + dst.a)/2;
}
```

But I would also like to remove the dot operator. I'm really not sure what the performance gains would be, it might be a useless micro-optimisation. Inlining the function yields a 100% increase in performance in FF at least. I was curious as to how to do it anyway. The original functions exist for fallback and ease of definition.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what _is_ your use case for using `eval()`?

Comment: It is not possible by regular expression. JS has a higher degree of complexity than regexp can handle.

Comment: I want to inline a function call that operates on single pixels. Basically I'm compiling a pixel shader function for the 2D canvas. The overhead of calling a function for each pixel is huge (on some implementations I've tried), so I am attempting to inline the function calls.

Comment: /[^a-z0-9]foo\.bar[^a-z0-9]/i

Comment: @Dale "avoiding instances like `"catfoo.barbar"`"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will avoid those instances

Comment: @Dale what about `cat_foo.bar_bar`?

Comment: @Dale and what about `var foo = "Hello foo.bar, how are you today?"`?

Comment: Yes that would match, but it isn't the string he showed. How can I identify all valid (in terms of js syntax) references to foo.bar safely in that string?

Comment: I suspect it's possible with regex under the assumption that the function is valid (which it will be). The problem I have is that I don't know what a valid object name token would match as. @Dale, that would have been my first assumption, but you can have all sorts of character like áéíóú which would be valid, you would match the foo.bar in áfoo.baré

Comment: @Dale, he said "like" so we should get the idea. The answer is: not possible with regexp. joeframbach's solution would work though.

Comment: If it's not possible, demonstrate an unmatchable scenario.

Comment: I can't see the word like. AHA I just saw it. Damn

Comment: @MattEsch, even if the function is correct syntax, you will need to account for comments, strings with double quotes and single quotes, escaped quotes etc.

Comment: Yes, the problematic scenarios are where arbitrary text may be inserted because it can read as code. Comments and inside strings. Are you asserting we can't match these constructs?

Comment: You can match in separate runs. Like first remove all comments, then match the instances inside strings and replace them with place-holders and then match the real instances. (unless i have forot another thing where `foo.bar` can occur. Well there is `foo["bar"]`, but that one is easy.)

Comment: Very good point... foo[getArbitraryString()]

Comment: @MattEsch Btw, you should at least "block" around your "inline functions" or else end up corrupting your scope: `out.a = (src.a + dst.a)/2;` goes `{out.a = (src.a + dst.a)/2;}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript parser written in javascript: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js

It will generate a nice parse tree. Good luck.

Comment: I respect that in general it's wrong to use regex to essentially parse a language which isn't regular, but I do feel that I can achieve what I need to in an easier way than parsing the entire expression into tokens. I don't think jslint can completely parse all valid syntax anyway. It didn't understand my use of catch(e if e instanceof EvalError)

Comment: You can do that quite safely with a regex with lookaround (looks what it's before or after  the looked for patternd, but doesn't match it). I've create one for your case, with eplaination on how to use it (or modify it, if you need it). Please, ask for further assistance with the regex if you nedd it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

```
  /(?=[{\s])foo.bar(?=[\s])/
```

with string.replace, like so:

```
  var replaced = original.replace(/(?=[{\s])foo.bar(?=[\s=])/g, "replacement");
```

The first group between brackets `[\s{]`, finds a { or spacing character (space, tab, and so on) before the word foo. The second group `[\s=]`finds spacing character or equals sign after bar. You can change it if you find there are other possibilities. `(?=...)` matches a string, but doesn't include it in the match. That means that the spacing character or the curly brace or equal sign are found but not included in the match, so the aren't replaced.

The final `/g` means that all matches are found. If you know there are only one you can omit it.

Comment: What about: `"var someFunction = function (foo) { /* set foo.bar to hello */ foo.bar = 'hello'; };"`?

Comment: I don't know which are exactly the requirements of the OP, but, even in this sample (and extreme case), replacing this text will not harm, as the result of the call of `eval` with the same or a different comment will be just the same. You could even argue that it can be between " or '. In that case, yep, it would fail, but is it possible, in a practical situation, that case? The OP should tell us (but I guess it's not possible). You look more like a mathematician theorizing that a programmer solving a problem in the easiest way. I think you are using cannons to kill mosquitoes.

Comment: @JotaBe Okay, perhaps i should pop up more examples: `"var someFunction = function (foo) { foo.bar = 'hello \'{ foo.bar }\' ';};`, `"var someFunction = function (foo) { foo.bar = 'hello'.replace(/. foo.bar ./, "foo");};` and many many more. I think this kind of theorizing is very important in order to make robust programs, otherwise i would not really call it "solving" the problem, but rather cheating the way around it until it bytes you.

Comment: No doubt you can find lots of cases that will break the code. More even in a dynamic language like js. So you can decide to do nothing because it can break. Engineering is about that. No company builds  bridges that can stand all kind of earthquakes. They build bridges that stand the worst eartquake that is somewhat probable. An eartquake harder than expected will break the bridge. But it's better to have a bridge that will break in strange circumstances than not having a bridge. The allowance would be lower in a program that controls a nuclear power plant. Other programming lang would be used

Comment: If it prooves to be to difficult to build a safe bridge, it may be a good idea to build a tunnel instead.

Comment: You like it or not, engineering is looking for a balance between cost and safety. With your idealistic thinking you would build a bridge that stands everything, but there's no budget. So you build nothing. In real life we look for compromises, in this case between safety and budget. And we prefer to have a bridge 99,8% safe that having no bridge at all. Do you make unit testing? Does your tests cover all possible cases? It would be way too expensive, so I'm sure you don't (they can cover 100% code, but I'm sure not all cases). You suffer from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis